# The Create View is redirecting to itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been trying to Auto Increment my ID (BookId). All views are working(Edit,Delete,Details,Index), but the Create one is not working very well because it redirect to itself every time I try to add a new book.

In my Controller I have the following:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Book/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(tbBooks tbbooks)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.tbBooks.Add(tbbooks);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(tbbooks);
}
```

And in the Create.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Book")){
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>tbBooks</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookId)    
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset> 
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I've already created the database with the table and the column "BookId" is set with the Identity Specification = Yes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDhEW.png)

Any help you can give me I'll appreciate,
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a lot of things are going on here:

First, you'd better specify in the Create method if it is a `[HttpGet]` (in the first method).

Second, your view has:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookId)
```

This doesn't make any sense, once your are not passing any value from the [HttpGet] method to your view.

Third, it's not usual to place a label for a hidden field. You usually don't want to show hidden fields.

Also, for the structure in your database, you'd probably need filling out the fields name, price, etc in your view. If your ID is auto-incremented, you probably don't need to handle it yourself, database will do that for you.

Finally, when you submit your form, what's probably happenning is that the if command below is false (you can place a breakpoint and check):

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

So the next command executed is:

```
return View(tbbooks);
```

Which makes you return to the View itself. I'm surprised you are not getting any errors. I suggest you take a look in some tutorials and actually use the code scaffolded by Visual Studio, which already contains some great indicators on how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ModelState.IsValid` property is returning false and hence it is executing the `Return View(tbbooks) line`. That means your form did not provide all the required values / some values were not acceptable as per the data annotation definition.

To know which valiations failed, In your razor view,

Change `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` to `@Html.ValidationSummary()`

and submit the Add form again. You will see the validation errors

The boolean parameter you passed to `ValidationSummary` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationSummary%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.Boolean%29) tells the system to exclude property Errors. that is why you could not see them.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSummary(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    bool excludePropertyErrors
)
```